# i want to users to download a file after updating the downloads counter on the database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to set up a download counter for files. My plan is: When a user clicks on the download button, the id of that file is sent to the download controller, the download controller updates the download column by 1 with its unique id, and then user is redirected back to the view, and download starts. I have found a way to send the id of a particular file to the download controller when the download button is clicked. I used a form with hidden fields in the view to send the id.
      I checked online, and i saw many download counters but most of them update textfiles. I want a column in the database to be updated, not text files. Here is my download form view:

```
   <form id="form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Download" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="ID" name="id"  value ="<?php echo $res->id; ?>"  class="wow fadeInUp">
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="ID" name="url"  value ="<?php echo $res->url; ?> class="wow fadeInUp">
    <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD" id="download" class="wow fadeInUp">
    </form>
```

This view sends id and other data to the download controller, here is my download controller:

```
  function index()
  { 
     $id = $this->input->post("id");
     $url = $this->input->post("url");
     $this->home_model->update_downloads_column($id);
      redirect("Music/".$url);
  }
```

i need a way forward. Right now, the downloads column on the database has been updated, how do i  now make download of that file start?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ajax to pass value and the anchor tag in html that has download attribute? 
check that here :

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Code:

```
<a href="/pathtofile/file.txt" id="download" download>
```

And then just do something like :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#download").on( "click",function () {
        var id = $('input[name=id]').val();
        var url = $('input[name=url]').val();
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: <?php echo base_url();?>+"Download",
            data: {id: id, url: url},
             success: function(){
                //if success do something
                }
             });
   });
})
</script>
```

So when you click anchor, download will start and ajax will pass id and url to controller.

Comment: so i do not need to put the input fields in a form tag?

Comment: You don't, you can pass them as base url 
`var id = <?php echo $res->id; ?> ;`

Comment: thank you very much, can you please tell me how to link ajax library, like a url or something please..im quite new to AJAX..thanks

Comment: I used jquery so you have to add this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks for that, but another thing please, is there any way to debug sort of, because right now the file downloads, but it dosen't update the column  on the database, i have linked the Jquery library, my link has an id of download, but it's not updating the column..thanks

Comment: This has to be inside of your html for you to be able to echo base url and all info and jquery library has to be loaded before this script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106911/discussion-between-marko-kunic-and-spunkalator).